# How can I start nest app with Postgress DB on Win 10?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, nest

I'm front dev and I need to test locally my front app with backend (nest js) and postgresql DB. Who can write me the right way How to run and connect to DB ? I get some errors on app start. I work on win 10 and there is my steps for start this app.

1. install postgresql
2. npm install for my nest js app
3. run pgAdmin4 and create DB for my app
4. npm start

There is my ormconfig

```
module.exports = {
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": process.env.POSTGRES_HOST || "localhost",
  "port": process.env.POSTGRES_PORT || 5432,
  "username": process.env.POSTGRES_USER || "", //<- Here I try to set all possible username
  "password": process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD || "", //<- Here I try to set all possible password
  "database": process.env.POSTGRES_DB || "my_database",
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": true
}
```

There is error that I encountered
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCKd3.png)

Also on other computer I try to do this and I get error like

```
[Nest]   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. 
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" (postgresql 14 with pgAdmin 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your typeormconfig.ts , you should write this:

```
 export class PostgresTypeormConfiguration implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory
    {
        createTypeOrmOptions(connectionName?: string): TypeOrmModuleOptions | Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> {
            const TypeOrmOptions:TypeOrmModuleOptions=
            {
             type: "postgres",
             host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST ,
             port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT ,
             username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER ,
             password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD ,
             database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
             entities: ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
             synchronize: true,
             logging: true
            }
            return TypeOrmOptions
        }
    }
```

and you should define this in your module like this:

```
@Module({
    imports:[TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({useClass:PostgresTypeormConfiguration})]
})
```

note: if you still got an error , you wrote one of the config option wrong in your .env file or you did not define .env file in your configModule